# No files will open from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, pdf, default-programs, mime-type, png

Whenever I double-click a file in Nautilus it does not open. See below screenshots for .pdf and .png files.

[image]

[image]

It does show the icon for document viewer for the .pdf file, but it still displays the error.

If I right-click on the .pdf or .png file and click "Open with " it still displays this error. If I right click on the file and click "Open with other application" and choose the default application, it still displays this error. If, however, I right-click on the file and click "Open with other application" and click on a different application than the default, it doesn't display an error, but it also doesn't open the file.

If I click Yes from the error in the above image, I get the following error.

[image]

I have tried reinstalling nautilus.
I have looked at my /usr/share/applications/defaults.list and it looks fine.
The files will open if I open them from within the default application such as document viewer or Image Viewer.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Welcome! What happens if you use the command `mimeopen <a_file.pdf>`?

Comment: @Kurankat It is version 18.04

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity it opens the .pdf file in LibreOffice Draw which is not the default that it shows when I am in Nautilus

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity when I run `mimeopen <a_file.jpg>`, it does the same thing. It opens in firefox when Image Viewer is the default that shows in Nautilus.